# Reloading the web page does not update img.src

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started learning HTML and JS and got stuck at this point. I am using "cataas" to update a new image but every time I reload the page, nothing changes.

```js
function loadCatPicture() {
  var img = document.getElementById('cat-picture');
  img.src = 'https://cataas.com/cat';
};

window.onload = function() {
  loadCatPicture();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Cats Sleep Anywhere</h1>
  <p>
    Cats sleep anywhere, any table, any chair.<br> Top of piano, window-ledge, in the middle, on the edge.<br> Open draw, empty shoe, anybody's lap will do.<br> Fitted in a cardboard box, in the cupboard with your frocks.<br> Anywhere! They don't care!
    Cats sleep anywhere.<br>
    <br>
    <img id="cat-picture">
    <b>Eleanor Farjeon</b></p>
  <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: I am using live server with vs code and when I reload nothing changes. Tested on safari, shows a different image but does not change

Comment: is your console showing errors?

Comment: This is happening due to browser caching. You can send something in querystring which send the new request instead of cached one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is probably just caching the image response from `cataas.com`.

Per the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images), you can just tack on some harmless `GET` parameters to the request URL that will be ignored by the server but ultimately trick your browser into not caching the response:

```js
function loadCatPicture() {
  var img = document.getElementById('cat-picture');
  img.src = 'https://cataas.com/cat?ver=' + (new Date().getTime());
};

window.onload = function() {
  loadCatPicture();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Cats Sleep Anywhere</h1>
  <p>
    Cats sleep anywhere, any table, any chair.<br> Top of piano, window-ledge, in the middle, on the edge.<br> Open draw, empty shoe, anybody's lap will do.<br> Fitted in a cardboard box, in the cupboard with your frocks.<br> Anywhere! They don't care!
    Cats sleep anywhere.<br>
    <br>
    <img id="cat-picture">
    <b>Eleanor Farjeon</b></p>
  <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that your browser is caching the image. Since the image URL doesn't actually change and just the actual image instead. to see a change in your code you would have to clear your browser's cache. In Chrome it's as easy as clearing your history ;)